# What is the interior of [0,1)?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I think it would be (0,1). I just need to check if my explanation makes sense. 1 is not an interior point as it doesn't belong to the set. 0 is not an interior point as the left neighborhood of 0 is not part of the set as it is a closed interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!  You are right.  I don't know how rigorous you need to be, but you can simply derive the answer using the definition of interior as well as constructing $\epsilon$-neighborhoods.  A way to go about proving that $(0,1)$ is the interior is assuming $[0,1]$ is the interior and showing a contradiction.

Note: I've been working on assignments dealing with interiors and $\epsilon$-neighborhoods, so this topic is really fresh for me.